# Install new most recent python package in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I could really do with installing matplotlib 1.1.0 on my ubunutu 11.10 system.

The current ubuntu package is at 1.0.1, how do I use the new one?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

- Uninstall the current `mathplotlib` package that you have installed.
- Download source from [the distribution site](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)
- [Compile and install](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html#installing-from-source)

Comment: Thanks, was fairly painless - I've been a bit pushed for time these days and was glad to find a solution that required absolutely no text editors.

Comment: If so, find anybody who builds it for you. If there is no such package from the stock source, it can't appear there magically.